# Laravel Voyager after install gives "Access denied" error for root@localhost

Tags: laravel, voyager

I'm having a problem with laravel voyager I tried installing it and it says "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found." I watched the tutorials on youtube. I tried finding the problem and I think this is the causing it, but I can't understand what's the problem. Can anyone help me

[image]

Comment: Unlike your question, the error message looks pretty clear to me. Are those the correct login details for `root@localhost`?

Comment: @underscore_d yes they are

Answer (score 0):

In the .env file, enter the database settings

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=mysql
DB_PASSWORD=mysql
```